# True and 1 and 1.0 evaluated to be same in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

Can anyone explain this behaviour of python dictionaries?

```
d = {}
d[True] = 'Magic'
d[1] = 'Cool'
d[1.0] = 'Hello'
print(d)

# {True: 'Hello'}
```

Why does it not print all the other (key, value) pairs?

Why does True, 1 and 1.0 is evaluated to be the same?

Comment: @Aran-Fey but the 1.0 part isn't addressed there right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, but is that really necessary? The answers do a good enough job explaining that sets (and dicts) eliminate items that hash and compare equal.

Comment: I'd say it's a necessary duplicate, then. Because of the confusion that could exist because `bool` is a subclass of `int`, while `float` isn't.. yes this is a duplicate, but I'm not going to fight to delete it. Useful dupe. damn I edited _after_ closure :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) of the 3 items `1, 1.0, True` is the same (it equals `1`). that's what python uses as the key for  dictionaries if there are no collisions. and as `1 == 1.0 == True` is also `True` there are no collisions.

here are more details about the [old implementation](https://fengsp.github.io/blog/2017/3/python-dictionary/) of python dictionaries. the new implementation does things along those lines (but preserves the order).

Comment: yes!! hashes are equal AND values are equal.

Comment: You can simply try: `True.__hash__()`

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and `True == 1` and `False == 0` is very much deliberate.