# The Second Element in A Dict Defined in Python keeps missing

Tags: python

Python's version is 3.

In Python’s Interpreter in Mac's terminal (console), I tried defining a couple of Dicts but found that all the second elements in those Dicts were always missing. See the code below:

```
>>> dictOne = {True: 'real', 1: 'one', 'two': 2}
>>> dictOne
{True: 'one', 'two': 2}

>>> dictTwo = {1: 'one', True: 'real', 'two': 2}
>>> dictTwo
{1: 'real', 'two': 2}

>>> dictThree = {1: 'one', True: 'real', False: 'fake', 'two': 2}
>>> dictThree
{1: 'real', False: 'fake', 'two': 2}
```

Boolean and Integer values seem to interfere with each other. What happened?

Comment: The keys in dictionaries are hashed in the internal data structure of the dictionary. If you try `print(hash(1.0))`, `print(hash(1))` and `print(hash(True))`,  you'll get the same hash. Since dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, the kv pair that remains is the last you set on the dictionary.

Comment: You should also post the python version you're using to make the question clear. It also seems that it has been answered a number of times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402133/true-and-1-and-1-0-evaluated-to-be-same-in-python-dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`True` and `1` mean the same thing to Python. (`True` is basically `bool(1)`, and `True == 1` evaluates to `True`)

Python dicts don't allow duplicate keys, and `True` and `1` are considered duplicates.

**EDIT:** Alexandre Juma gave a nice explanation of this. Essentially, dict keys are hashed, and `hash(1)` and `hash(True)` return the same thing.